# Marionette children.findByIndex(x) in a compositeView?

Tags: marionette

fairly new to javascript and backbone Marionette, and I cant seem to figure out how to do this.
I want to select a child view from a compositeView by index (or any of the other selectors the docs say are available for the inherited collectionview (from babysitter).).

ie from within myCompositeView:

```
someMethod: function(index){
    this.children.findByIndex(index);
 },
 ...
```

how can I access the collectionView from a compositeView such that I can findByIndex or findByModel etc and get a reference to the actual Marionette View?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using v1.0.0-beta6 of Marionette, as this is where the feature you need was introduced.

CompositeView extends directly from CollectionView, so calling `this.children.findByIndex` should work, as long as you're using the right version of Marionette.